# C++ Calculation program not responding

Tags: c++, product, series

I was trying to make a program that finds the greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits in a 1000-digit number which I defined as a long int called series.

It first calculates it for the 13 digith on the right than comes to the left as it multiplies the number by the number on the left and divide it by the number on the right.

For example: it finds the products of 988.-1000. digits Then it divides it by the 1000th number and multiplies it by 987th number. Until there is no number left in the left side of this (or in the more significant digit). It compares these numbers and find the greatest one. Or at least it was supposed to...

When I run the program it does not respond and closes, giving me an empty console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int seridigit(int r,long int series){
    int digit=(series%(int)pow(10,r))-(series%(int)pow(10,r-1));
    return digit;
}

int main()
{
    int largest_found,current;
    long int series = 731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450;
    current = series%((int)pow(10,13));
    largest_found = current;
    for (int i=1;i<=987;i++){
        int current = current/seridigit(i,series)*seridigit(i+13,series);
        if (current > largest_found){
            largest_found = current;
        }
    }
    cout << "Greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number: "<< largest_found <<endl;
}
```

Comment: That 1000-digit number is far to large to store in a `long`.

Comment: Wow. On what kind of a computer can you fit such a huge number into a single `long int`?

Comment: Perhaps processing that large number as a string would prove more feasible?

Comment: To solve Project Euler problems you will typically have to us techniques that C++ does not provide in any fundamental way. I checked and see that I solved it with a char string. Your compiler should have balked at that number, and it did not?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Thought of using strings but never thought it was required/ would fix the problem, though ı still wonder why the computer cant handle the number, not giving an answer for a long time is one thing, not respounding is another.

Comment: @newbie: a computer has a finite amount of memory. it cannot hold all numbers, as there are infinitely many numbers. But further: a `long int` is 64 bits. It goes from 2^32 to -(2^32+1).

Answer (score -2):

where is return 0; at the bottom of the code  whenever return 0; is not at the last part of the code the console just prints out nothing.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for this, even though it did not help the question itself it made me fixe my code a bit. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: *"whenever `return 0;` is not at the last part of the code the console just prints out nothing."* - that's just plain wrong. `return 0;` is optional for [`main`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) (though I'd still recommend writing it)